# why does this page say java is running if I don't have the java plugin installed? How do i find and disable the java plugin for firefox, and others?

Tags: java

why does this page say java is running if I don't have the java plugin installed? How do i find and disable the java plugin for firefox, and others? http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp
I need to make sure that java is diabled so that my pc doesn't get exploited.
to answer this question i will accept:

how to find the java plugin
why the java plugin isn't listed in firefox
how to remove the java plugin
other info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Java 6, like I do. you can disable the IcedTea plugin.
but the exploit is only for java 7.
and you can see your version on this page: javatester.org